# Configure a many to one relationship in a Owned Entity in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, owned-types

I have a class that is an entity in the DB and has a owned entity:

```
public class EntityOne
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public OwnedEntity OwnedEntity { get; set; }
}
```

I have the owned entity with a list with the type of another persisted entity:

```
public class OwnedEntity
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<EntityTwo> EntityTwo { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the EntityTwo:

```
public class EntityTwo
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
 
        // all other properties
}
```

**I need to create the relationship between EntityOne and EntityTwo as a many to one, but the property navigation is in my owned entity. How can I do that?**

I tried to create a property navigation of my owned entity like this:

```
public class EntityTwo
{
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public OwnedEntity OwnedEntity { get; set; }

        public int OwnedEntityId { get; set; }

        // all other properties
}
```

And the map:

```
builder.HasOne(prop => prop.OwnedEntity)
                .WithMany(prop => prop.EntityTwo)
                .HasForeignKey(prop => prop.OwnedEntityId);
```

But I got an error because ef tries to make my owned entity as a entity table.

Then, I tried to reference the parent entity:

```
public class EntityTwo
{
            public int Id { get; set; }
    
            public EntityOne EntityOne { get; set; }
    
            public int EntityOneId { get; set; }
    
            // all other properties
}
```

And mapping with inner properties:

```
builder.HasOne(prop => prop.EntityOne.OwnedEntity)
                .WithMany(prop => prop.EntityTwo)
                .HasForeignKey(prop => prop.EntityOne.OwnedEntityId);
```

But it didn't work and i got another ef error:

```
Error: The expression 'prop => prop.EntityOne.OwnedEntity' is not a valid member access expression. The expression should represent a simple property or field access: 't => t.MyProperty'. (Parameter 'memberAccessExpression')
```

**So, is there any way to create this relationship?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who want to know how I solved it, I did it all inside the map configuration of the entity one, using the [OwnsMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#collections-of-owned-types). First, I changed the one-to-many reference of EntityTwo to the OwnedEntity:

```
public class EntityTwo
{
            public int Id { get; set; }
    
            public OwnedEntity OwnedEntity { get; set; }
    
            public int OwnedEntityId { get; set; }
    
            // all other properties
}
```

Then, i made this map (builder of the EntityOne):

```
builder.OwnsOne(prop => prop.OwnedEntity, subBuilder =>
{
    // all map configurations of OwnedEntity

    subBuilder.OwnsMany(prop => prop.EntityTwo, ownedBuilder =>
    {
        ownedBuilder.HasOne(prop => prop.EntityTwo)
        .WithMany(prop => prop.OwnedEntity)
        .HasForeignKey(prop => prop.EntityTwoId);

        // all map configurations of EntityTwo
    }
}
```

That's it.